# How do I create an Android app that allows me to control a robot fitted with raspberry pi?

Tags: android, python, web-services, raspberry-pi, robotics

I would like to create an Android App that allows me to remotely control a robot fitted with raspberry pi using Wi-Fi. I have searched various threads and one of the ways is to make my rspi a web server. I've come across this code that I should use on my Android app to make http request.

```
    class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 0).show();
}
}
```

To make the connection,I have to write this code:

```
new RequestTask().execute("http://192.168.1.145:80/3");
```

However, my question is:
After connecting to my Raspi,how do I send python code from the android app to be executed on my Raspi?

Thanks.

Comment: On a side note HttpClient is deprecated, if you intend to use this over a WIFI [this](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot) may interest you. Check [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=31596) and [this](http://dishingtech.blogspot.jp/2012/01/realtek-wi-fi-direct-programming-guide.html)

Comment: i think you should send web request with android in Java and handle them on the raspbery pi which handle them in pyton.

Comment: `http://192.168.1.145:80/3`. So that /3 would be all info you send to the webserver on the raspberry? That is not much. Do you think to implement more parameters yet? About the python code for the raspberry? How come that python code is on your Android device? Makes no sense. I would think you develop python code for the raspberry on the raspberry itself or on a pc. You forgot to tell how that webserver and python code are connected.

Comment: You might try looking at how PiUi works. A [blog post](http://blog.davidsingleton.org/introducing-piui/) about how it works and the [github](https://github.com/dps/piui). It turns your Pi into a wifi spot and you can connect to it via web. Could be something.